# Incorrectly making new collection from existing collections

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I am still a beginner with C# so I am sure I am missing some fundamental concept here but I am struggling with this.
**I am trying to make a new collection from two existing collections.**

The first is a `Dictionary<string, someModel[]>`
The second is a `Dictionary<string, string>`
I am trying to find matches between the two dicts keys and if they match make a new `myOtherModel`with the values from the two dicts, but if they don't match I still want to make  new `myOtherModel` but with an empty string for the missing value then add all those new `myOtherModel` will be added to a list.
**The new myModel object will be one of two scenarios**
For example:  Dict1.Keys = 1,2,3,4....100. Dict2.Keys = 5,9,27,55

```
myList.Add(new myModel = {1, "", someModel[]}) //did not find a match 
myList.Add(new myModel = {5, dict2.MatchingValue, someModel[]}) // did find a match
```

So basically, compare two dictionaries, for each item in the larger dictionary, make a new myModel with the item's values (one of them will be empty). But if that item's key matches a key in the other dictionary, grab the second dictionary's value and slap that in the new myModel 
I tried messing around with a Tuples but I wasn't able to manipulate them how I wanted to. 
This is what I have so far, but instead of giving me 490 items (the count from dict1) I get the 44k (the amount of the two being multiplied together)

```
foreach (var pair in dict1)
        {
            foreach (var item in dict2)
            {
                if (item.Key == pair.Key)
                {
                    var x = new myModel()
                    {
                        prop1 = item.Value,
                        prop2 = pair.Key,
                        prop3 = pair.Value
                    }; 
                    myListOfModels.add(x);

                }
                else
                {
                    var x = new myModel()
                    {
                        prop1 = "",
                        prop2 = pair.Key,
                        prop3 = pair.Value
                    };
                  myListOfModels.add(x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through the second collection each time you iterate through the first collection which is why you're seeing too many results.  You can easily simplify your code with a simple bit of Linq...

```
    foreach (var pair in dict1)
    {
        // Get the matched value.  If there isn't one it should return the default value for a string.
        var matchedValue = dict2.Where(x => x.Key == pair.Key).Select(x => x.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        var x = new myModel()
        {
            prop1 = matchedValue,
            prop2 = pair.Key,
            prop3 = pair.Value
        };
        myListOfModels.add(x);
    }
```